# What is the westerly index?

Tags: wind, pressure

This was asked in aviation stack exchange and the best answer (credit:ymb1) was:

The westerly index is the Trenberth Z1 index (Trenberth 1976), which is the departure of the monthly mean pressure difference between Auckland and Christchurch (near 44°S) from its mean over the 1961–90 period.

Can anyone expand on that? And explain how it is calculated?